# NeoVim from Packer to Lazy

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I am currently starting my first project and i wanted to use NeoVim to learn it from scratch and to be faster in the future. I watched the video from theprimeagen "0 to LSP", but his built is not up to date, f. ex. his lsp.lua file doesn´t work. I also wanted to switch from packer to lazy.

First, i tried to make a switch from packer to lazy, because in my research, i found out that this would be better.I changed the packer file from primeagen to a new lazy file with the following code:

```
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"

if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
    vim.fn.system({
        "git",
        "clone",
        "--filter=blob:none",
        "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
        "--branch=stable",
        lazypath
    })
end

vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

local plugins = {
    'wbthomason/packer.nvim',
    {
        'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim',
        tag = '0.1.0',
        dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' }
    },
    {
        'rose-pine/neovim',
        as = 'rose-pine',
        config = function()
            vim.cmd('colorscheme rose-pine')
        end
    },
    {
        "folke/trouble.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("trouble").setup {
                icons = false,
                -- Ihre Konfiguration hier
            }
        end
    },
    {
        'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter',
        run = function()
            local ts_update = require('nvim-treesitter.install').update({ with_sync = true })
            ts_update()
        end
    },
    "nvim-treesitter/playground",
    "theprimeagen/harpoon",
    "theprimeagen/refactoring.nvim",
    "mbbill/undotree",
    "tpope/vim-fugitive",
    "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-context",
    'VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim',
    branch = 'v1.x',
    dependencies = {
        -- LSP Support
        'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
        'williamboman/mason.nvim',
        'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',
        -- Autocompletion
        'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp',
        'hrsh7th/cmp-buffer',
        'hrsh7th/cmp-path',
        'saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip',
        'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp',
        'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua',
        -- Snippets
        'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip',
        'rafamadriz/friendly-snippets',
    }
}

local opts = {
    -- Ihre Konfigurationsoptionen hier
}

require("lazy").setup(plugins, opts)
```

Can someone tell me why this doesn´t work? And could someone recommend me a NeoVim built?

Thx in Advance :)

Comment: Could you tell what doesn't work tho? I copied your config and started nvim, it just automatically installed some plugins and kinda work as it seems, the only problem is that the `lsp-zero.nvim`'s branch and dependencies should be grouped together along with its plugin id like the following syntax: `..., { 'VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim', branch = ..., dependencies = { ... } }, ...`

Comment: it says to me: "Re-sourcing your config is not supported in lazy.nvim " when i use the :so command. Also f. ex. when i am using my shortcut for using telescope, when i had my packer config it worked, but now when i try to use it, i get the following error: E5108: Error executing lua: ...ck/packer/start/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/pick
ers.lua:347: Invalid 'event': 'User TelescopeFindPre'                     
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_exec_autocmds'
        ...ck/packer/start/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/pickers.lua:347: in func
tion 'find'
       ...

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Kickstart Nvim](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim), it's what I did when I started using Lazy because it gives you a very basic config. It's just easier to set your own config based on Kickstart because it gives you just what you need to start with a useful Neovim editor, as opposite to other distros, which gives you yet another editor (just my opinion).

This is my Neovim config, feel free to clone it, it's not perfect, but it works very well for me. I'm using Lazy and following the `spec` approach to define plugins.

- Dotfiles: https://github.com/asilvam133/.nvim
- Approach: https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim#%EF%B8%8F-importing-specs-config--opts

Now, there are a couple of things that you have to change:

1. Remove the Packer plugin, you won't need it anymore since you are using Lazy.
2. Follow the `Migration Guide` in https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim, because there are some keywords that have different names or merged.
3. The `dependencies` key needs to be defined per plugin. If you are migrating from packer, basically is what you have as `requires`.
4. In the color scheme plugin, I have this:

```lua
  {
    'rose-pine/neovim',
    name = 'rose-pine',
    lazy = false,
    priority = 1000,
    opts = {
      disable_background = true,
    },
    config = function()
      local p = require('rose-pine.palette')

      vim.cmd.colorscheme('rose-pine')
      vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'Normal', { bg = 'none' })
      vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'NormalFloat', { bg = 'none' })
      vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'String', { fg = p.rose })
      vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'Number', { fg = p.rose })
      vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'Float', { fg = p.rose })
      vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'Constant', { fg = p.rose })
      vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'Character', { fg = p.rose })
    end,
  },
```

Instead of `as`, use `name`.

`lazy = false` and `priority = 1000` to load it from startup.

In the `config` function, the important one is the `vim.cmd.colorscheme('rose-pine')`, which will set the color scheme to be loaded.

The rest of settings inside the `config` function are just to get rid of most of the gold colors in those groups.

5. I don't know if it's required, but you should try to set each plugin as a table:

```lua
{
  'tpope/vim-fugitive',
  event = 'BufWinEnter',
},
```

The `BufWinEnter` event ensures Fugitive to be loaded as soon as you enter a buffer. https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html#BufWinEnter

I hope this helps you.